# Is there an example of a live candlestick chart being updated?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I'd like to have a candlestick chart that plots trade data from a websocket feed.  The incoming trade data has price, volume, and date-Time.

I've looked over all the documentation and demos, but I can't find any information on how to update an existing chart data point.  In my case, I need to be able to update the close field on an existing candlestick.

Comment: Not familiar with this library, but their API seems pretty thorough. Have you checked out their page on [OHLCCandleStick](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.0.0/classes/ohlccandlestick.html)? I'm guessing `setValues()`.

Comment: Found example: https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/#/edit/lcjs_example_0202_ohlcPlotAutomaticPacking

Comment: For web socket data feeding, there's an example in Github for LightningChart JS https://arction.github.io/lcjs-showcase-trading/
It's reading data from WorldTradingData.com